# Custom decision manager authorisation in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, authorization

I have a specific authorisation system in my application (asked by my managers). It is based on Joomla. Users are attached to usergroups. Every action (i.e page) in my application are resources and for each resources I have set an access level. I have then to compare the resource access level with the usergroups of the current user to grant access or not to this specific resource. 
All those informations are stored in database which are in return entities in Symfony : 
User <- ManyToMany -> Usergroups
Menu (all resources with path and access level)

I thought about the Voter system. It is kind alike of what I would want, I think. Can I hijack the support function for this ?

```
protected function supports($user, $resource)
    {
        //get usergroups of the $user => $usergroups
        //get the access level of the resource => $resource_access
        // if the attribute isn't one we support, return false
        if (!in_array($usergroups, $resource_access)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The get the usergroups and the access level of the resource I will have to do some queries in the database. To use this, then I would to use the denyAccessUnlessGranted() function in all my controller (seems redundant by the way) ?

Do you think it would work or there is another system more suited for this case ? I thought of doing the control in a listener to the kernel.request event too. 
Hope I am clear enough, I'm new to symfony and still have some issues to understand how everything are related and working.

Comment: You can use [Security annotations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) in your `Controller` classes or methods. A custom voter is easy enough, but can you equate your `UserGroups` to a [Role](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles)?

Comment: A User may have several UserGroups so it would mean that I'll need to declare a role for all combination of usergroups, highly time consuming I think.

Comment: Just implement `getRoles()` to include your usergroups prepending `ROLE_`. Something like `return $this->roles + array_map(function($group) { return 'ROLE_' . $group->name; }, $this->getUserGroups());`. Just a thought.

Comment: Good question, I'm agree with msg you should annotate your controller and develop a custom voter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voter component should be a good fit for this, as its a passive approach that lets you implement any logic in a way where its fixable through code, without modifying any database specific acl tree not managed by symfony itself.

Voters are called if you use `denyAccessUnlessGranted()` or `isGranted()` either through code, annotation or twig.
Lets take a look at how you want to check if the current user has access to view the index page:

```
class SomeController {
    public function index() {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('VIEW', '/index');
        // or use some magic method to replace '/index' with wathever you require,
        // like injecting $request->getUri(), just make sure your voter can
        // parse it quickly.

        // ...
    }
}
```

Now build the a very simple voter:

```
class ViewPageVoter extends Voter
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em) {
      $this->em = $em;
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
    {
        return is_string($subject) && substr($subject, 0, 1) === '/';
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)
    {
      $currentUser = $token->getUser();

      if(!$currentUser) {
        // no user or authentication, deny
        return false;
      }

      // Do the query to see if the user is allowed to view the resource.
      // $this->em->getRepository(...) or
      // $this->em->getConnection()
      // 
      // $attribute = VIEW
      // $subject = '/index'
      // $currentUser = authenticated user
      // return TRUE if allowed, return FALSE if not.
    }
}
```

As a nice bonus you can easily see additional details on security voters in the /_profiler of that request, also indicating their respective vote on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have hard times to apply it to my case though. In a simple case, like the index page of an application. What I have to do is, get the usergroups of the logged user. That information I can have it from the ```$token->getUser()```. After I have to get from the database the access level required for the resource requested. I can have the path requested from the ```$request``` variable and then the access level with a query to the database. With this example, I don't see how to apply voters. I don't have $attribute or $subject and have no use of them.

Comment: @Azeann I've exchanged the example in the answer to a more simplistic one voting on a string your controller provides.